# Problem with pear after upgrading php

Tags: php, doctrine, pear

I upgraded the WAMP from php 5.3.0 to php 5.3.5
now I'm having a problem with pear that I just cant' solve
When I try to install Doctrine pear keeps telling me that Doctrine requires php version 5.3.2 but my installed version in 5.3.0

Where does it get this information that my installed version is 5.3.0?

I am in the directory
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5

I run the pear command from here. I even downloaded the new go-pear.phar from pear.php.net and ran it from this directory. It created the pear file for me.

Where is the old setting stuck? Is it somewhere in registry?

Comment: What is the output of `php -v` on the command line?

Comment: when I am in the php5.3.5 directory the output is php5.3.5

Comment: I looks like there is some old config data stuck somewhere and pear uses some old config file. I just don't know how to get rid of it and start like its a brand new pear installation

Comment: Run `pear config-show`. Where does the `PHP CLI/CGI binary` and `PEAR directory` point to?

Comment: I don't have anything in config-show about cli or cgi. I have bin_dir points to c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5 and php_bin points to c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\php.exe

Comment: I see in config-show that user configuration file points to the old php5.3.0 directory. But how do I change that? Is that even important?

Comment: Use `pear config-set <var> <value>`

Answer (score 0):

PEAR stores the PHP binary it uses in its configuration.

View the configuration:

```
$ pear config-show
$ pear config-get php_bin
```

You can change it with

```
$ pear config-set php_bin /path/to/php
```

Also, you might need to update `pear.bat` to have the correct php location. Changing the config and upgrading pear (possibly with -f when it's already at the latest version) will fix it, too.